# Decimal Formatting is not working in SSRS and XML as DataSource

Tags: wcf, reporting-services

I have WCF service as Datasource for SSRS rdl reports. As I was using some Decimal Formatting for my one of the columns. But, the output shows exactly same as Decimal Format String (`"#,#0.00"`) instead of applying the format to the actual value(`0.00`).

**Decimal Formatting**

```
=Format(Fields!Column1.Value,"#,#0.00")
```

**Output**

```
#,#0.00
```

The actual value was `0.00`. Donot understand what is the issue. Any help to this problem will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you fixed your issue?

Comment: Yes, The problem was with xml datasource. Its not recognizing the datatypes properly. When I cast it to appropriate type then it works fine with the above syntax. (Eg: In Query window cast decimal type something like, `Column1 (Decimal)`)

Comment: Thanks for the info. Please post an answer explaining what you did, it could help people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using XML as datasource, the Type of data is not recognized properly by default. So, Casting the appropriate type in SSRS designer Query window can sort out the problem.

**Code**

```
<Query>
<Method Namespace="http://tempuri.org/" Name="TitlesorItemRec">
</Method>
<SoapAction>http://tempuri.org/IService1/TitlesorItemRec</SoapAction>
<ElementPath IgnoreNamespaces="true">
TitlesorItemRecResponse{}/TitlesorItemRecResult{}/_Pitac{}/PropTitlesorItemRec{Copy (integer),CreatedOn (Date),InfoType, Title,copiesreceipt (integer),itemno,podetailid (integer)}
</ElementPath>
</Query>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have one too many #s. Try `=Format(Fields!Column1.Value,"#,0.00")`